Get value from two tables with only one model class
I have a model looking something like this:
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

Id, Name and TypeId are stored in one table, but TypeName is stored in another as it going to be used multiple places. It is a 1-to-Many relation where TypeId is the foreign key.
The type table just has the id and name.
I want to know if it is possible to get the TypeName without having to make another class to represent the other table. And preferably if it can be done as part of the entity type configuration, so i won't have to include it every time.
I tried experimenting with .SplitToTable() but was not able to get it to work. Same thing with .HasOne().
My best attempt at using .SplitToTable()
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
{
    // Relevant part of file
    builder.ToTable("Orders");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(x => x.ResourceTypeId);
    builder.SplitToTable("Types", tb =>
        {
            tb.Property(x => x.TypeName).HasColumnName("Name");
        });
}

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone who commented!
I ended up making a class for the type entity, add it to Order like public ResourceType Type { get; set; } and have it auto included using builder.Navigation(x => x.Type).AutoInclude()

Do you try to convert the sql
select a.Id,a.Name,a.TypeId,b.TypeName from Orders a join Type b on a.TypeId == b.TypeId to ef core query?  And you want to create another model for Type table, am I right?

@TinyWang Regarding the SQL, yes. But I do NOT want to create another model for Type table.

Could you pls help try this ?`var result =
from a in context.Orders
join b in context.Types on a.TypeId equals b.TypeId
select new Orders
{
Id = a.Id,
Name = a.Name,
TypeId = a.TypeId,
TypeName = b.TypeName
};
var ordersResult = result.ToList();`

Or maybe Entity Splitting is what you actually wanted? You should be able to basically take that example and strip it down to your use-case.

Can you post your best attempt at SplitToTable() and we can go from there?

With that model, there is no correlation between TypeId and TypeName.  If you want TypeName to depend on TypeId, you'll need to put it into a different model/table.  You can always flatten the data when you query it for your presentation layer (DTO)

Please [edit] the question and turn it into a [mre].

Why do you want to do that? If Type is reused elsewhere and is in its own table, it's a seperate entity type. Trying to work around that will not make things better.

@Fildor, I have added my best attempt to the question.

I would guess that just the TypeId Column config is missing and it should work?

@Fildor Could you provide an example on what you mean by that?

@Jineapple I am just trying to avoid having to use .Include() everywhere in the system, as i will need it all the time.

@Fakima Then use auto include. That is the proper solution, not putting two separate tables into one Entity.
Also, you don't even necessarily need include, if you map to DTOs.

I mean: right above tb.Property(x => x.TypeName).HasColumnName("Name"); you put tb.Property(x => x.TypeId).HasColumnName("Id"); ?

Look at Shadow property
